# Retrieving data on dynamic controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dynamic-controls

I am using dynamically created controls and need to retrieve information about the control at runtime.

```
If IsLoaded <> "free" Then
        flow_display.Controls.Clear()
        For x As Integer = 0 To populate.Count - 1
            If populate(x).parentID = 2 Then
                Dim NewPicBox As PictureBox = New PictureBox
                NewPicBox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(697, 50)
                NewPicBox.ImageLocation = pw_imgLink & populate(x).imageID

                AddHandler NewPicBox.Click, AddressOf catWindow
                flow_display.Controls.Add(NewPicBox)
            End If
        Next
        IsLoaded = "free"

    End If
End Sub
```

Here I create the control when the user clicks on the appropriate label. Right now the catWindow sub is empty. I need to figure out which button is clicked and figure out its location on the populate list. I have tried a few things and from what I've read from other questions can't seem to find anything the helps. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finding out which PictureBox is pressed, your catWindow Sub should look like this:

```
Public Sub catWindow(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim box As PictureBox = TryCast(sender, PictureBox)
    If box Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'Now "box" refers to the PictureBox that was pressed
    '...
End Sub
```

If you want to find it's location in the populate list, you will need to iterate through the list until you find the matching box. You could also pre-empt a property on your PictureBox that isn't doing anything else and use it to store the index. Older forms tools used to have a .Tag property especially for this kind of thing. But really, the need to do this smells like a design flaw to me.

FWIW, I'd rewrite your original sample like this:

```
If IsLoaded <> "free" Then

    flow_display.SuspendLayout()
    flow_display.Controls.Clear()

    For Each box As PictureBox In populate
                        .Where(Function(p) p.parentID = 2)
                        .Select(Function(p) New PictureBox() With {
                             .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(697, 50),
                             .ImageLocation pw_imgLink & p.imageID })

        AddHandler box.Click, AddressOf catWindow
        flow_display.Controls.Add(box)
    Next box

    flow_display.ResumeLayout()
    IsLoaded = "free"
End If
```

Comment: I am pulling a series of information from my database and placing it on the list. Would it be easier to accomplish this through an array or should I go about this in a completely different direction? Oh and that catWindow thing worked, THANKS!

Comment: @spkelly86 look into databinding